# My networking service is not getting is failing in lubuntu

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, lubuntu

I have been trying to start networking service, but its not working. I am getting the below error.I tried many ways but none worked.

```
root@cerberos:~# service networking restart
Job for networking.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status networking.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

After entering systemctl command I am getting this :

```
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/networking.service.d
           └─50-insserv.conf-$network.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-04-04 14:47:36 UTC; 5min ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 749 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 746 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] && udevadm settle (code=exited
 Main PID: 749 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 04 14:47:36 cerberos systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Apr 04 14:47:36 cerberos ifup[749]: Cannot find device "eth0"
Apr 04 14:47:36 cerberos ifup[749]: Failed to bring up eth0.
Apr 04 14:47:36 cerberos systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 04 14:47:36 cerberos systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
Apr 04 14:47:36 cerberos systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 04 14:47:36 cerberos systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
lines 1-17/17 (END)
```

The below configuration file of /etc/network/interfaces gives me this.

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Source interfaces
# Please check /etc/network/interfaces.d before changing this file
# as interfaces may have been defined in /etc/network/interfaces.d
# See LP: #1262951
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*.cfg

and the content of /etc/network/interfaces.d/ shows 

uto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.4.0.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.4.0.1
dns-nameservers 10.4.1.12
```

Actually I am unable to understand why ifup is unable to find eth0 device and how can make it work?

Comment: What version lubuntu? Edit your `/etc/network/interfaces` file (or .cfg file) and change `uto eth0` to `auto eth0`. Show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

Comment: My version is Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS. I get this results after using:                           
      cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml                                           
      cat: '/etc/netplan/*.yaml': No such file or directory

Comment: Ah! Did you edit or add the file in `/etc/network/interfaces.d`? Have you changed the `uto eth0` to `auto eth0` and retried the Internet? Show me `ls -al /etc/network/interfaces.d` and `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: Also show me `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`.

Comment: No I didn't add anything to `/etc/network/interfaces.d`. I just missed auto while it copying here. The internet is working fine.

Comment: `sierra@coryVM:~$ ls -al /etc/network/interfaces.d`
`total 8`
`drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 25  2016 .`
`drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Apr  8 11:08 ..`

Comment: for `sudo lshw -C network` the content of the file is long therefore I am unable to post it here. But the content of `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` is  `sierra@coryVM:~$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false`

Comment: You lost me. You say "The internet is working fine.". I thought that you had a problem? No? Also, for your last two comments, and for the `sudo lshw -C network` you just copy the output to the clipboard, edit your question, paste in the clipboard, select the text, and format it with the {} icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you need to do this...

Change `/etc/network/interfaces` to look like this...

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Source interfaces
# Please check /etc/network/interfaces.d before changing this file
# as interfaces may have been defined in /etc/network/interfaces.d
# See LP: #1262951
#    source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*.cfg

#    and the content of /etc/network/interfaces.d/ shows 

#   auto eth0
#    iface eth0 inet static
#    address 10.4.0.2
#    netmask 255.255.255.0
#    gateway 10.4.0.1
#    dns-nameservers 10.4.1.12
```

Then go to the NetworkManager GUI, create a new `Wired Connection`, set it for manual addressing, and enter the above static info there. Here's what it should look like... mine will look a little different than yours, as I'm on 18.10, but you'll get the idea...

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lottt for your help and prompt reply...!!! :) It worked.